# Undefined symbols for architecture arm64 caused by UIImage.resize (Xcode 11)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, arm64

While trying to build an app in Bitrise (with fastlane) I get the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64
> Symbol: (extension in Swift):Swift.Sequence< where A.Element: Swift.Comparable>.max() -> A.Element?
> Referenced from: (extension in myapp):__C.UIImage.resize(maxDimension: Swift.Double) -> __C.UIImage in UIImage+Resize.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I don't know exactly what is going wrong here. Locally the build and archiving were successful. I tried some solutions for similar questions here on stackoverflow but they are pointing a different issue. Or I don't know which library is maybe not linked properly.

Update:

The function resize is an extension for UIImage added by myself:

```
import Foundation

extension UIImage {
    func resize(maxDimension: Double) -> UIImage {
        let maxCG = CGFloat(maxDimension)
        if [self.size.width, self.size.height].max()! < maxCG {
            return self
        }
        let factor = self.size.width > self.size.height ? maxCG / self.size.width :  maxCG / self.size.height
        let canvasSize = CGSize(width: self.size.width * factor, height: self.size.height * factor)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(canvasSize, false, self.scale)
        defer { UIGraphicsEndImageContext() }
        self.draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: canvasSize))
        return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    }
}
```

Comment: resize is a function in an extension file wrote by myself (see update above).

Comment: Thank you matt, that solved the problem. How did you found out what exactly was the reason for this error? Because I have now the next one ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: the problem was this part of the code:

```
[self.size.width, self.size.height].max()!
```

I replaced it by:

```
let referenceLength = self.size.width >= self.size.height ? self.size.width : self.size.height;
```

Now it works.

Comment: Did you figure out _why_ it happened?